# ImageView Onclick Animation

Tags: java, android, dialog, imageview

Below is a picture of my app, I am currently using a modified version of [this](http://twocentscode.blogspot.ie/2014/02/three-level-expandable-listview.html) app to show my expandable content. Now my problem is with my ImageView, I currently have 3 layouts, one for the main dialog (with listview), one for the listview title & arrow and one for the item details (item row once expanded). I want to add animation to the ImageView so when you click the image or title textview, the list will expand and animate the change. How can I do this? I cannot get the onClick to work because it doesn't know there are 2 imageviews, it seens only one...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I will assume that your ImageView is this arrow inside your ListView element (because you didn't write it clearly enough).

You probably shouldnt try to attach onClickListener to your ImageView at all (nor to your ListView element title). The good way of implementing what you want you achieve would be to use ListView's onItemClickListener to detect clicks performed on specific items inside your listview, and then expanding appropriate expandable content.

Comment: Good suggestion, I believe that will work. Do you know how to animate my ImageView to rotate 180 degree clockwise and counter-clockwise(to return to the original position)? 

I am able to animate and rotate the arrow 180 clockwise to point up when expanded but I cannot rotate it counter-clockwise to return it to the original position when the list is collapsed.

Comment: I'd advice you to take a look at ViewPropertyAnimator

Comment: do you have any examples?

Comment: example for the rotation?
You should probably be able to do this by with: CW (clockwise) `arrowImageView.animate().rotationBy(180);` and CCW (counter-clockwise): `arrowImageView.animate().rotationBy(-180);`